# How to get children/attachments in header?

Tags: images, genesis-theme-framework, slideshow

I am trying to add a slider to my custom page template.  I would like to have the flexibility to upload images from the add media button in the editor and have no restrictions on the number of images.  Below is the code I am using:

```
/* 
Template Name: Property
*/ 

add_action('genesis_entry_header','property_slider',15);
function property_slider() { 

// array with parameters
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => -1,  
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);
if ( $images = get_children( $args ) ) {

    echo '<div id="slider_wrap"><div id="slider">';

            foreach( $images as $image ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' );
            }

    echo '</div></div>'; 
}

}
```

The above is outputting all the images in my gallery.  How do I output only the images "uploaded to this page"?

Your input is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Codex: get_children - examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children#Examples):

> If you just want to get or display attachments, it's probably a little easier to use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post) instead.

So you might go on and do that, the link in above cite leads to an example.

Besides that change your code to:

```
global $post;
// array with parameters
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => -1,  
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);
$images = get_children( $args );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $img_id => $img ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $img_id, 'full' );
    }
}
```

Main difference being that you have to do:

```
global $post;
```

because you're outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your input and pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. @William

Comment: Would you accept a small fee to help me add bxslider to my website :) ?

Comment: If I remember correctly there are some pretty neat solutions/plugins out there to use bxslider with WP. I guess I just hindered myself making money :D @William

Comment: hehe... yep there are quite a few I check :)  But none of them tell you how implement [this example](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1).  your expertise would be appreciated.  let me know if you are interested :)